# Glassfish error upon attempting to use in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

Good day

I am trying to study JAVA EE so I installed the Glassfish 3. But when I attempted to deploy my project on Netbeans 6.9. I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Shutting down v3 due to startup exception : Address already in use: bind: 8080=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectorHandler@106433d
```

And the server won't start.

It seems like that the port 8080 is already in used.

I go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services but I don't know which application to kill because the port is not indicated there. How can I know which application is currently running at port 8080 so I could kill it?

EDIT: As per your suggestions, I did the netstat -aon

The result is as follows:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3700           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4724
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4848           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4724
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4724
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8181           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4724
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8686           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4724
```

Can I kill this? I don't know what this means -> "LISTENING".. Sorry I don't understand this result much..

Anyway I killed the application as suggested by @Jigar Joshi and it Worked! 
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error message tells that the port is already binded with some other process now as you are running on windows machine

&

> go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services but I don't know which application I want to kill because the port is not indicated there. How can I know which application is currently running at port 8080 so I could kill it?

goto command prompt

```
netstat -aon
```

it will show you something like

```
 TCP    192.1.200.48:2053      24.43.246.60:443       ESTABLISHED     248
 TCP    192.1.200.48:2055      24.43.246.60:443       ESTABLISHED     248
 TCP    192.1.200.48:2126      213.146.189.201:12350  ESTABLISHED     1308
 TCP    192.1.200.48:3918      192.1.200.2:8073       ESTABLISHED     1504
 TCP    192.1.200.48:3975      192.1.200.11:49892     TIME_WAIT       0
 TCP    192.1.200.48:3976      192.1.200.11:49892     TIME_WAIT       0
 TCP    192.1.200.48:4039      209.85.153.100:80      ESTABLISHED     248
 TCP    192.1.200.48:8080      209.85.153.100:80      ESTABLISHED     248
```

check which process has binded your port. here in above example its `248` now if you are sure that you need to kill that process fire

Linux:

```
kill -9 248
```

Windows:

```
taskkill /f /pid 248
```

it will kill that process

Comment: @Jigar Joshi - org.life.java I posted the result above and found the one using the port 8080.. can i kill the 4742? Thank you

Comment: **yes** go ahead at your risk.

Comment: @Jigar Joshi - org.life.java  Shukriya :)

Comment: @Jigar Joshi - org.life.java you're welcome != "Maligayang Pagdating" hahahaha... you're welcome == "Walang Anuman". Don't use the auto-translate

Answer (score 2):

- Go to Command prompt
- Type the following command

  netstat -aon | findstr "8080"

  *ex : TCP    10.12.230.222:2049     10.12.240.69:8080      ESTABLISHED     **3476***
- Get the process id from the last column and run the following command

  tasklist | findstr "**3476**"

  for example you might get like this

  *firefox.exe                 3476 RDP-Tcp#5               0    168,668 K*
- go to task manager and kill the firefox or whatever running on 8080 and start the server.

Comment: I posted the result above and found the one using the port 8080.. can i kill the 4742? Thank you

Comment: @newbie tasklist | findstr "4742", does it have a name ?

Answer (score 1):

Java App servers typically run on port 8080.  Look from Apache Tomcat or another java web server that you might have installed and started.